# OSI model in VB.Net 2010

Tags: vb.net, networking, osi

I need to implement a communication protocol in VB.net 2010. Kind of an OSI model/architecture, but smaller using a vb class for each layer, how can I link them efficiently?

Normally, the communication buffer would travel from the bottom to the top or top to bottom. 
For now, I have a main class where each layer is declared and I use delegates in each layer to link it with the upper and lower layer.

Is there any kind of pattern that I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say - you can't do this as I don't think you will get able to get any lower than OSI layer 5 using managed VB.NET (someone correct me if I'm wrong)

The point being that VB.NET is a higher level language and the functionality is provided to you in prebuilt classes, the lower level communication is handled by the framework and is some cases the actual hardware you are using.

My opinion is that this is probably the wrong language to use for this - C/C++ are probably more appropriate or even assembly language.

Comment: Thanks Matt for you feedback.

Comment: I try to build a kind of structure in VB that looks like a OSI model. Nothing too deep, just a few layers that need to communication between each other. In C, each layer just need to include .h and call the functions.